# Creating new virtual server or Sub-server breaks all existing domains

Tags: dns, apache, virtualhost, webmin

Hellow,

I have 3 domains and several subdomains in Virtualmin which works fine.
For the past 1 year, I didn't do any server maintenance except for updating the packages which shown in the Webmin control panel.

#### PROBLEM

I tried to add a subdomain(Sub server) for an existing domain. Now all the domains and subdomains point to **public_html** of the newly created virtual server or sub-server.

Eg: If I want to add a subdmain/Subserver to www.example1.com all the other existing domains and subdomains points to  /home/example1/domains/test.example1.com/public_html

Or If I create a new virtual server for www.example2.com all the other existing domains and subdomains points to  /home/example2/public_html

Webmin -> Apache Webserver -> Existing virtual host looks like this.

```
Type            Address     Port    Server Name             Document Root
Virtual Server  Any         80      medlk.myolddomain.com   /home/abcd/domains/medlk.myolddomain.com/public_html 
Virtual Server  Any         80      mydocs.myolddomain.com  /home/abcd/domains/mydocs.myolddomain.com/public_html 
Virtual Server  128.123.33.334  80  test.myolddomain.com /home/abcd/domains/test.myolddomain.lk/public_html
```

It shows the IP address where it should show "Any".

> The newly created virtual server doesn't share the IP address.
>   Instead, all the domains with that IP address point to the newly
>   created **public_html** folder.

To resolve it, either I have to,
1. Delete the new virtual server that I have created or
2. Edit virtual server -> Enabled features -> DISABLE Apache website (Remove check mark)
3. Change the IP address of that server

I have no clue about what is wrong. I would really appreciate your advice on approaching this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### RESOLVED

For now I have resolved the issue by editing, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/xxxx.conf`

The change I made in the first line, `<VirtualHost 128.xxx.xxx.227:80> Changed it to, <VirtualHost *:80>`